# Backbone.js - What is the best way to check a checkbox

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

My backbone model has a boolean value (isRegistered).  When I render out the view I want to have a checkbox checked or unchecked depending on the true/false value of the boolean.

My current effort looks like this:

```
<input id="isRegisteredCheckbox" checked="<%= isRegistered ? 'checked': ''"/>
```

this doesn't work because according to the W3C Specification the checked attribute needs to be completely removed to uncheck a checkbox.

How do I do it using backbone template?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" <%= item.visible ? "checked" : "" %> value="<%= item.id %>"/>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `checked=` part. just print out checked in the tag if it needs to be checked.

---

**EDIT**

Now that we've determined that just printing "checked" out is valid html, you might try for simplicity:

render:

```
var registered;
var tmpl = _.template(your template);
isRegistered ? registered = 'checked' : registered = '';
var tmpl_data = _.extend(this.model.toJSON(), {registered: registered}); // or whatever values you need to add
$(this.el).html(tmpl(tmpl_data));
```

template:

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ registered }}>
```

No need for messy conditionals in your template using this method.

Comment: While your suggestion will render in browsers, the OP mentioned 'W3C specs'. Depending on which spec he is referring to the checked attribute may require a a corresponding value (even if its "").

Comment: @EBarr it's valid in HTML 4 Strict, HTML 4 Transitional and HTML5.  I mean I guess it's possible it's not valid in HTML4, but, man if HTML4 strict & transitional, AND html 5 aren't "W3C specs", I'm not sure what would constitute W3C specs.

Comment: This works in all browsers we're inmplementing for basically >IE6 definitely the easiest and neatest answer too

Comment: I was thinking xhtml ..it was all the rage when I was a kid:-)  I looked at the html 4/5 specs again, and hadn't realized that it allows for both the condensed and long versions of boolean attributes.

Comment: @reach4thelasers that's because it's valid markup even back to HTML 3.2 which was released in 1997.  Only XHTML renders this markup invalid, and you shouldn't ever use XHTML for thousands of reasons ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a test to enclose `checked='checked'`

```
<input id="isRegisteredCheckbox" <% if (isRegistered) { %>checked="checked"<% } %> />
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to use a `Decorator` for this cases. I expose here an example of how it can looks like:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var MyModelDecorator = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function( opts ){
    this.model = opts.model;
  },

  toJSON: function(){
    var json =
      _.extend(
        this.model.toJSON(),
        {
          checked: this.checked(),
          css_classes: this.cssClasses()
        }
      );

    return json;
  },

  checked: function(){
    result = "";
    if( this.model.get( "checked" ) ) result += "checked=\"true\"";
    return result;
  },

  cssClasses: function(){
    result = "";
    if( this.model.get( "checked" ) )         result += " checked";
    if( this.model.get( "key" ) == "value" )  result += " important";
    return result;
  }
});
```

I have added an extra `css_classes` *decorator attribute* so you can see this approach can be a common solution for several situations.

Your `View.render` can look like this:

```
// code simplified and not tested
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: _.template( "<input id=\"isRegisteredCheckbox\" <%= checked %> class=\"<%= css_classes %>\" />" ),

  render: function(){
    var decorator = new MyModelDecorator({ model: this.model });
    this.$el.html( this.template( decorator.toJSON() ) );
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple way of doing it.

```
<input <% if(isRegistered) print("CHECKED"); %>  type="checkbox" id="isRegisteredCheckbox" />
```

Notice that i use <% and not <%= for the condition.

You could just set the value of isRegistered to "CHECKED" or "" in your model and call

```
<input id="isRegisteredCheckbox" <%= registered %> />
```

with something like

```
serialize: function() {
  var isChecked = (isRegistered) ? "CHECKED" : "";
  return {registered : ischecked};
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I inherited someone's Django + hamlpy (HAML) + Backbone.js + Undescore.js with Mustache templates (what a mess!)

Haml processing in hamlpy didn't exactly like:

```
%input{ :checked => {{isChecked}} ? true : None }
```

Or any similar thing. I got a Django hamlpy stacktrace.

I managed to hack it by using Mustache's inverted sections (see: http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html)

```
{#isChecked}
%input{:checked => 'true' }
{/isChecked}
{^isChecked}
 %input{ ... without the checked attribute ... }
{/isChecked}
```

Anyway, hope that helps some poor Googler from wasting hours of their life force!